# Error MSB4057: The target "Build" does not exist in the project working with Continuous integration with MSbuild for U-SQL

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am working with integrating continous integration with vsts using MSBuild for U-SQL reffering the link : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2017/10/24/continuous-integration-made-easy-with-msbuild-support-for-u-sql-preview/

But i am facing below issue while working with VSTS Build server

```
Source\TrainingUsql\TrainingUsql\TrainingUsql\TrainingUsql.usqlproj (0, 0)
Source\TrainingUsql\TrainingUsql\TrainingUsql\TrainingUsql.usqlproj(0,0): Error MSB4057: The target "Build" does not exist in the project.
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
```

I have followed all the steps given in link and added the below MSBuild argument :

```
/p:USQLSDKPath=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/USQLMSBuild/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.1019-preview/build/runtime /p:USQLTargetType=SyntaxCheck /p:DataRoot=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the hosted agent or a private agent?

Comment: What's the result if you build the u-sql project locally in VS? If it's failed locally, you should debug the errors for your project.

Comment: @DanielMann, Yes i am using the private agent

Comment: @Marina-MSFT, I have tried to build u-sql project locally in vs using MSBuild command prompt, which buid successfully.

Comment: @DiptiMamidala You should use you project name and the package version you install instead in the MSBuild arguments as `/p:USQLSDKPath=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/{projectname}/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.{version_you_intalled}/build/runtime /p:USQLTargetType=SyntaxCheck /p:DataRoot=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`. And also please check if you select **Visual Studio Version** correctly for VS Build task. After make sure the arguments and VS version are correct, what's the result of the build?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT, I am receiving the same error as i received previously

Source\TrainingUsql\TrainingUsql\TrainingUsql\TrainingUsql.usqlproj(0,0): Error MSB4057: The target "Build" does not exist in the project.

Yes, i have selected the visual studio 2015 as visual studio version and platform "Any Cpu" and Configuration "Release"

Comment: @DiptiMamidala Can you share the project on one drive?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT, Yes, please share your one drive account

Comment: @Marina-MSFT, i have shared the project.. please check

Comment: @DiptiMamidala Got it!

Comment: @Marina-MSFT, are you able to build successfully on vsts?

Comment: @DiptiMamidala Sorry for the delay, I was out of office for last two days. I can build your project successful on VSTS. You can check details in my answer.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT, if i want to build U-SQL project on TFS,so am i able to build using the same steps ?

Actually i have tried to build the U-SQL project on TFS using xaml build defination with the same steps, but it returns with error "TrainingUsql.usqlproj: The target "Build" does not exist in the project."

Comment: Yes, you can use the same steps for TFS build definition. You just need to setup a private agent for TFS on the same machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can build successful. Below is my settings and build logs for your reference:

[image]

[image]

```
******************************************************************************
Finishing: NuGet restore
******************************************************************************
Evaluating condition for step: 'Build solution USQLDemoProject/USQLDemoProject.sln'
Evaluating: succeeded()
Evaluating succeeded:
=> (Boolean) True
Expanded: True
Result: True
******************************************************************************
Starting: Build solution USQLDemoProject/USQLDemoProject.sln
******************************************************************************
==============================================================================
Task         : Visual Studio Build
Description  : Build with MSBuild and set the Visual Studio version property
Version      : 1.120.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613727)
==============================================================================
VstsTaskSdk 0.8.2 commit
Entering D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.120.0\VSBuild.ps1.
Loading resource strings from: D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.120.0\Task.json
Loaded 8 strings.
SYSTEM_CULTURE: 'en-US'
Loading resource strings from: D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.120.0\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
Loaded 8 strings.
INPUT_VSVERSION: '14.0'
INPUT_MSBUILDARCHITECTURE: 'x86'
INPUT_MSBUILDARGS: '/p:USQLSDKPath=D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.1019-preview\build\runtime;USQLTargetType=SyntaxCheck;DataRoot=D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject'
INPUT_SOLUTION: 'D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\USQLDemoProject.sln'
INPUT_PLATFORM: 'any cpu'
INPUT_CONFIGURATION: 'release'
INPUT_CLEAN: 'false'
Converted to bool: False
INPUT_MAXIMUMCPUCOUNT: 'false'
Converted to bool: False
INPUT_RESTORENUGETPACKAGES: 'false'
Converted to bool: False
INPUT_LOGPROJECTEVENTS: 'false'
Converted to bool: False
INPUT_CREATELOGFILE: 'false'
Converted to bool: False
INPUT_VSLOCATION (empty)
INPUT_MSBUILDLOCATION (empty)
INPUT_MSBUILDVERSION (empty)
Loading module from path 'D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.120.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\MSBuildHelpers.psm1'.
Loading resource strings from: D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.120.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\module.json
Loaded 9 strings.
SYSTEM_CULTURE: 'en-US'
Loading resource strings from: D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.120.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
Loaded 9 strings.
Exporting function 'Format-MSBuildArguments'.
Exporting function 'Invoke-BuildTools'.
Exporting function 'Get-MSBuildPath'.
Exporting function 'Get-SolutionFiles'.
Exporting function 'Get-VisualStudio_15_0'.
Exporting function 'Select-MSBuildPath'.
Importing function 'Format-MSBuildArguments'.
Importing function 'Get-MSBuildPath'.
Importing function 'Get-SolutionFiles'.
Importing function 'Get-VisualStudio_15_0'.
Importing function 'Invoke-BuildTools'.
Importing function 'Select-MSBuildPath'.
Entering Get-SolutionFiles.
Solution: 'D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\USQLDemoProject.sln'
Leaving Get-SolutionFiles.
Entering Select-VSVersion.
PreferredVersion: '14.0'
Entering Get-VSPath.
Version: '14.0'
Leaving Get-VSPath.
Leaving Select-VSVersion.
Entering Select-MSBuildPath.
PreferredVersion: '14.0'
Architecture: 'x86'
Defaulted MSBuild location method to: version
Entering Get-MSBuildPath.
Version: '14.0'
Architecture: 'x86'
Loading Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL
Not found.
Loading Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL
MSBuild: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe
Leaving Get-MSBuildPath.
Leaving Select-MSBuildPath.
Entering Format-MSBuildArguments.
MSBuildArguments: '/p:USQLSDKPath=D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.1019-preview\build\runtime;USQLTargetType=SyntaxCheck;DataRoot=D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject'
Platform: 'any cpu'
Configuration: 'release'
VSVersion: '14.0'
MaximumCpuCount: 'False'
AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT: 'VSTS_fc52d179-f3fd-460b-adb1-5ac84bd0e765_build_40_1819'
Leaving Format-MSBuildArguments.
Entering Invoke-BuildTools.
NuGetRestore: 'False'
SolutionFiles: 'D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\USQLDemoProject.sln'
MSBuildLocation: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe'
MSBuildArguments: '/p:USQLSDKPath=D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.1019-preview\build\runtime;USQLTargetType=SyntaxCheck;DataRoot=D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_fc52d179-f3fd-460b-adb1-5ac84bd0e765_build_40_1819"'
Clean: 'False'
NoTimelineLogger: 'True'
CreateLogFile: 'False'
Entering Invoke-MSBuild.
ProjectFile: 'D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\USQLDemoProject.sln'
MSBuildPath: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe'
AdditionalArguments: '/p:USQLSDKPath=D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.1019-preview\build\runtime;USQLTargetType=SyntaxCheck;DataRoot=D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_fc52d179-f3fd-460b-adb1-5ac84bd0e765_build_40_1819"'
NoTimelineLogger: 'True'
Asserting leaf path exists: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe'
Asserting leaf path exists: 'D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.120.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll'
Entering Invoke-VstsTool.
FileName: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe'
Arguments: '"D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\USQLDemoProject.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.120.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=|SolutionDir=D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.120.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /p:USQLSDKPath=D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.1019-preview\build\runtime;USQLTargetType=SyntaxCheck;DataRoot=D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_fc52d179-f3fd-460b-adb1-5ac84bd0e765_build_40_1819"'
RequireExitCodeZero: 'True'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe" "D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\USQLDemoProject.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.120.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=|SolutionDir=D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.120.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /p:USQLSDKPath=D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.1019-preview\build\runtime;USQLTargetType=SyntaxCheck;DataRoot=D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_fc52d179-f3fd-460b-adb1-5ac84bd0e765_build_40_1819"
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 10/30/2017 3:33:02 PM.
Project "D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\USQLDemoProject.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "release|any cpu".
Project "D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\USQLDemoProject.sln" (1) is building "D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\USQLDemoProject\USQLDemoProject.usqlproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin\Release\".
  Creating directory "obj\Release\".
USqlCompilerTarget:
  Building Script: 
  Build All Scripts in 'USQLDemoProject.usqlproj' ...
  Building 'Script.usql' ...
  D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.1019-preview\build\runtime\LocalRunHelper.exe compile -Shallow -FlatDir -Script "D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\USQLDemoProject\bin\Release\Script\Script.usql" -WorkDir "D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\USQLDemoProject\bin\Release\Script" -DataRoot "D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject" -Temp "D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\USQLDemoProject\bin\Release\Script\_TMP" -DumpCommonResult "D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\USQLDemoProject\bin\Release\Script\Script.usql.comresult" -DumpResult "D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\USQLDemoProject\bin\Release\Script\Script.usql.xml"  -SkipInputCheck
  Build suceeded
CoreCompile:
Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  Copying file from "obj\Release\Algebra.xml" to "bin\Release\Algebra.xml".
  USQLDemoProject -> D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\USQLDemoProject\bin\Release\Algebra.xml
Done Building Project "D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\USQLDemoProject\USQLDemoProject.usqlproj" (default targets).
Project "D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\USQLDemoProject.sln" (1) is building "D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin\Release\".
  Creating directory "obj\Release\".
GenerateBindingRedirects:
  No suggested binding redirects from ResolveAssemblyReferences.
CoreCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.1019-preview\lib\net45\Microsoft.Analytics.Diagnostics.dll /reference:D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.1019-preview\lib\net45\Microsoft.Analytics.Interfaces.dll /reference:D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.1019-preview\lib\net45\Microsoft.Analytics.Interfaces.Streaming.dll /reference:D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.1019-preview\lib\net45\Microsoft.Analytics.Types.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\M...
  Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin
_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
  Copying file from "D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.1019-preview\lib\net45\Microsoft.Analytics.Diagnostics.dll" to "bin\Release\Microsoft.Analytics.Diagnostics.dll".
  Copying file from "D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.1019-preview\lib\net45\Microsoft.Analytics.Interfaces.dll" to "bin\Release\Microsoft.Analytics.Interfaces.dll".
  Copying file from "D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.1019-preview\lib\net45\Microsoft.Analytics.Interfaces.Streaming.dll" to "bin\Release\Microsoft.Analytics.Interfaces.Streaming.dll".
  Copying file from "D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.1019-preview\lib\net45\Microsoft.Analytics.Types.dll" to "bin\Release\Microsoft.Analytics.Types.dll".
_CopyAppConfigFile:
  Copying file from "App.config" to "bin\Release\ConsoleApp1.exe.config".
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  Copying file from "obj\Release\ConsoleApp1.exe" to "bin\Release\ConsoleApp1.exe".
  ConsoleApp1 -> D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\ConsoleApp1\bin\Release\ConsoleApp1.exe
  Copying file from "obj\Release\ConsoleApp1.pdb" to "bin\Release\ConsoleApp1.pdb".
Done Building Project "D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj" (default targets).
Done Building Project "D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\8\s\USQLDemoProject\USQLDemoProject.sln" (default targets).
Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:07.24
Exit code: 0
Leaving Invoke-VstsTool.
Leaving Invoke-MSBuild.
Leaving Invoke-BuildTools.
Leaving D:\marina\newTFSPCagent\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.120.0\VSBuild.ps1.
******************************************************************************
Finishing: Build solution USQLDemoProject/USQLDemoProject.sln
```

---

Comment: @Marina-MSFT, Why is it important to install Microsoft.Azure.DataLakeAndStreamAnalyticsToolsForVS2015 tools for VS2015 ? As i refereed the article, it says that "By using MSBuild, customers can orchestrate, automate and build U-SQL projects in many environments including those where Visual Studio isn't installed" So if we don't install the tools for vsts and add just "Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.1019-preview" nuget package  , isn't it work ?

Comment: You just need to install the workload (Data storage and processing) for usql project and install the nuget package. So after creating the usql project, and add the nuget package, you can also use msbuild for the project.

Comment: @Marina Liu - MSFT, I followed the same steps you provided but it is not working for me. I am using hosted agent. Can you please help.