# Azure Data lake analytics CI/CD - Build error

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to build CI/CD for Azure Data lake analytics - USQL code and when i build the code using Visual studio build option in VSTS getting the below error - Using the Private agent for taking the build -
C:\Users\a.sivananthan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\DataLake\MsBuild\1.0\Usql.targets(35,7): Error MSB4064: The "OutputAssembly" parameter is not supported by the "USqlCompilerTask" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property. C:\Users\a.sivananthan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\DataLake\MsBuild\1.0\Usql.targets(33,5): Error MSB4063: The "USqlCompilerTask" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: What's the result if you build the project on that agent machine manually? What're settings of Visual Studio Build task?

Comment: I have my agent in my desktop where i have my visual studio code..i dont have a seperate virtual machine as a private agent..I use Nuget restore Path to solution, packages.config, or project.json - packages.config and Destination directory - $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\ADLAUSQL1\packages and build parameters as below - Solution - ADLAUSQL1.sln Visual Studio Version - Visual Studio 2015 MSBuild Arguments - /p:USQLSDKPath=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ADLAUSQL1/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.180223/build/runtime /p:USQLTargetType=SyntaxCheck /p:DataRoot=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)

Comment: I get this warning message in my build - ##[warning]C:\Users\a.sivananthan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\DataLake\MsBuild\1.0\Usql.targets(9,3): Warning MSB4011: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\vs-agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.131.0\_work\4\s\ADLAUSQL1\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.180223\build\runtime\UsqlSDKBuild.targets (9,3)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored. [C:\vs-agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.131.0\_work\4\s\ADLAUSQL1\ADLAUSQL1.usqlproj]

Comment: Pls let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Data lake analytics CI/CD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49574154/azure-data-lake-analytics-ci-cd)

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new simple project? If so, you can share it on the OneDrive.

Comment: Yes raised this as a seperate question since i didnt find any specific answers in google..

Comment: Sure will do..can you pls share your email id..thanks

Comment: You can just share the sample project on the OneDrive. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/share-onedrive-files-and-folders-9fcc2f7d-de0c-4cec-93b0-a82024800c07?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Thanks Starian..I created a new USQL project and its working fine now..Thanks

Comment: Great! I post an answer that you can [accept it as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new project can deal with that issue.