# Path for DataRoot in VSTS for USQL build defintion with USQLTargetType=SyntaxCheck for hosted agent

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, u-sql

I am working on generating builds for U-SQL using

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2017/10/24/continuous-integration-made-easy-with-msbuild-support-for-u-sql-preview/.

I got an error

> "Error MSB4057: The target “Build” does not exist in the project working with Continuous integration with MSbuild for U-SQL

which I was able to fix it by referring to 
[Error MSB4057: The target "Build" does not exist in the project working with Continuous integration with MSbuild for U-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46950853/error-msb4057-the-target-build-does-not-exist-in-the-project-working-with-con)"

Currently I am blocked on one thing.

When I use `USQLTargetType=SyntaxCheck` in parameter it asks for `DataRoot` to be provided.

- What path should I provide for `DataRoot`?
- On my local machine I provided `USQLDataRoot` folder path and it works fine and builds successfully
- I am using hosted agent for building solution

Comment: What's DataRoot actual value you specified? `/p:USQLTargetType=SyntaxCheck /p:DataRoot=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` works fine for me (Referred to that blog).

Comment: Thank you for the update. In the U-SQL project I am using dlls which are part of the solution. refer below for the sample snippet
------------------------------------
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Testing];

USING Testing;
--------------
I am getting following error
 Error E_CSC_USER_DDLENTITYDOESNOTEXIST: Assembly 'master.[Newtonsoft.Json]' does not exist.
Error E_CSC_USER_DDLENTITYDOESNOTEXIST: Assembly 'master.Testing' does not exist.

any suggestions to fix this

Comment: Do you include these dlls to the source control? Can you share a sample project on the OneDrive?

Answer (score 0):

The DataRoot designates the folder on your local machine that will contain the local U-SQL catalog as well as the files that you can reference using the same relative path that you can use on the cluster.

So you would chose the folder that contains the data and meta data that you need for your build to succeed.

Comment: But how would I provide the folder details in VSTS build definition which is using a hosted agent to run the build

Comment: Currently you have to make sure you have registered the assemblies to the data root folder before building the U-SQL script as we cannot find these catalog references unless they exists in the data root folder. Soon we will have a new feature enabling you to reference a U-SQL database project that contains all database objects definitions, the build process can then find the assemblies through reference management.